# Is Matthew 13:24-30 affirming the divine theodicy for the problem of evil in the story of Adam and Eve? Or does it shift blame to a feckless god?

Tags: matthew, theodicy

Is Matthew 13:24-30 affirming the divine theodicy for the problem of evil in the story of Adam and Eve? Or does it shift blame to a feckless god?:

> [Mat 13:24-30 NASB95] [24] Jesus presented another parable to them, saying, "The kingdom of heaven may be compared to a man who sowed good seed in his field. **[25] "But while his men were sleeping, his enemy came and sowed tares among the wheat, and went away.** [26] "But when the wheat sprouted and bore grain, then the tares became evident also. [27] "The slaves of the landowner came and said to him, 'Sir, did you not sow good seed in your field? How then does it have tares?' **[28] "And he said to them, 'An enemy has done this!'** The slaves said to him, 'Do you want us, then, to go and gather them up?' [29] "But he said, 'No; for while you are gathering up the tares, you may uproot the wheat with them. [30] 'Allow both to grow together until the harvest; and in the time of the harvest I will say to the reapers, "First gather up the tares and bind them in bundles to burn them up; but gather the wheat into my barn."'"

Related:

> [Gen 3:9 NASB95] [9] Then the LORD God called to the man, and said to him, "Where are you?"

> [Exo 31:17 NIV] [17] It will be a sign between me and the Israelites forever, for in six days the LORD made the heavens and the earth, and on the seventh day he rested and was refreshed.' "

> [Psa 121:1-8 NLT] [1] A song for pilgrims ascending to Jerusalem. I look up to the mountains--does my help come from there? [2] My help comes from the LORD, who made heaven and earth! [3] He will not let you stumble; the one who watches over you will not slumber. [4] Indeed, he who watches over Israel never slumbers or sleeps. [5] The LORD himself watches over you! The LORD stands beside you as your protective shade. [6] The sun will not harm you by day, nor the moon at night. [7] The LORD keeps you from all harm and watches over your life. [8] The LORD keeps watch over you as you come and go, both now and forever.

> [Jhn 12:40 RSV] [40] "He has blinded their eyes and hardened their heart, lest they should see with their eyes and perceive with their heart, and turn for me to heal them."

> [Rom 11:1-10 NASB95] [1] I say then, God has not rejected His people, has He? May it never be! For I too am an Israelite, a descendant of Abraham, of the tribe of Benjamin. [2] God has not rejected His people whom He foreknew. Or do you not know what the Scripture says in [the passage about] Elijah, how he pleads with God against Israel? [3] "Lord, THEY HAVE KILLED YOUR PROPHETS, THEY HAVE TORN DOWN YOUR ALTARS, AND I ALONE AM LEFT, AND THEY ARE SEEKING MY LIFE." [4] But what is the divine response to him? "I HAVE KEPT for Myself SEVEN THOUSAND MEN WHO HAVE NOT BOWED THE KNEE TO BAAL." [5] In the same way then, there has also come to be at the present time a remnant according to [God's] gracious choice. [6] But if it is by grace, it is no longer on the basis of works, otherwise grace is no longer grace. [7] What then? What Israel is seeking, it has not obtained, but those who were chosen obtained it, and the rest were hardened; [8] just as it is written, "GOD GAVE THEM A SPIRIT OF STUPOR, EYES TO SEE NOT AND EARS TO HEAR NOT, DOWN TO THIS VERY DAY." [9] And David says, "LET THEIR TABLE BECOME A SNARE AND A TRAP, AND A STUMBLING BLOCK AND A RETRIBUTION TO THEM. [10] "LET THEIR EYES BE DARKENED TO SEE NOT, AND BEND THEIR BACKS FOREVER."

Comment: I think it would be fair to ask what kind of theodical perspective Matthew has here. But I can't see any direct relevance to Adam & Eve in this passage. Jesus seems to be speaking about the present through most of this part of Matthew - as seen for example by the many references to "this age".

Answer (score 1):

The parable of the Weeds comes in Matthew 13:24-30. In this parable is repeated mention of an "enemy". So does this word "enemy" say anything about where evil has ultimately come from? eg: Did evil ultimately come from Adam and Eve or, as per this question, a "feckless God"?

Points that this parable illustrate come in Jesus' explanation of it in Matthew 13:36-43. I will not repeat them all here except the broad idea of "The harvest is the close of the age" [v39], when the "weeds" go into the fiery furnace but the righteous to the Kingdom of their Father.

This parable is about final end judgement. The fact that an "enemy" sowed the weeds tells us nothing about how that enemy came to be an "enemy". ie: where evil ultimately came from.

Would God create an "enemy"? This parable does not answer this question.  To answer such a question we might consider whether God could have a holy motive for creating that which was so against Him as to merit to be decribed as an "enemy".

I do not find mention of holy motives hinted at in this parable. [Romans 9:22 mention "wrath" and "power"]. So no,  Matthew 13:24-30 does not tell us exactly how this enemy" came into existence. This parable does not address the problem of where evil ultimately came from.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that the logic of the theodicy in Matthew appeals to dualism? IE: A crafty lesser god is responsible for the bad seed: 

[2Co 4:4 KJV] [4] In whom the god of this world hath blinded the minds of them which believe not, lest the light of the glorious gospel of Christ, who is the image of God, should shine unto them.

Comment: @Ruminator If a lesser god, the god of this world, made evil, there is still the question of, how did that god come into being? My understanding is, all things from, through and to Him as in Romans 9:36. ie: Perfect God had a holy motive for making something which was not Himself and not being Himself it was dependent; not all-knowing; not perfect of itself; ie: imperfect and less than holy.

Comment: So really, it doesn't make for a good theodicy, does it?!

Comment: @Ruminator Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

**Definitions**

Theodicy - [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodicy)

> In the philosophy of religion, a theodicy (/θiːˈɒdɪsi/; meaning
> 'vindication of God', from Ancient Greek θεός theos, "god" and δίκη
> dikē, "justice") is an argument that attempts to resolve the problem
> of evil that arises when omnipotence, omnibenevolence, and omniscience
> are all simultaneously ascribed to God. Unlike a defence, which
> merely tries to demonstrate that the coexistence of God and evil is
> logically possible, a theodicy additionally provides a framework
> wherein God's existence is considered plausible

feck·​less ˈfek-ləs - [From Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feckless)
1: WEAK, INEFFECTIVE
She can't rely on her feckless son.
2: WORTHLESS, IRRESPONSIBLE
a feckless maneuver that could only serve to strengthen the enemy

Parable - [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable)

> A parable is a succinct, didactic story, in prose or verse, that
> illustrates one or more instructive lessons or principles. It differs
> from a fable in that fables employ animals, plants, inanimate objects,
> or forces of nature as characters, whereas parables have human
> characters. A parable is a type of metaphorical analogy.

**Restating the question**
Is Matthew 13:24-30 affirming the divine theodicy for the problem of evil in the story of Adam and Eve? Or does it shift blame to a feckless god?

I'm going to assume that "a feckless god" is the "enemy" who "came and sowed weeds"

**Answer**

1. The parable Jesus gives us in Matthew 13:24-30 is not intended to be an "argument that attempts to resolve the problem of evil"
2. This story does not relate to the story of Adam and Eve.
3. The parable does not characterize the enemy as a weak, ineffective, worthless or irresponsible "god".

**Explanation of the parable**
Jesus explained his intent later in chapter 13

> 36 Then he left the crowds and went into the house. And his disciples
> came to him, saying, “Explain to us the parable of the weeds of the
> field.” 37 He answered, “The one who sows the good seed is the Son of
> Man. 38 The field is the world, and the good seed is the sons of the
> kingdom. The weeds are the sons of the evil one, 39 and the enemy who
> sowed them is the devil. The harvest is the end of the age, and the
> reapers are angels. 40 Just as the weeds are gathered and burned with
> fire, so will it be at the end of the age. 41 The Son of Man will send
> his angels, and they will gather out of his kingdom all causes of sin
> and all law-breakers, 42 and throw them into the fiery furnace. In
> that place there will be weeping and gnashing of teeth. 43 Then the
> righteous will shine like the sun in the kingdom of their Father. He
> who has ears, let him hear.

Jesus teachings revolved around the kingdom of heaven. He talked about what the kingdom of heaven was like and the characteristics of the people who will be in the kingdom of heaven and the characteristics of those who are not in the kingdom of heaven.

In this parable Jesus is teaching that:

1. Those who are followers of the Son of Man belong in the kingdom.
2. Those who don't follow Jesus are sons of the evil one.
3. The members of the kingdom of heaven will be separated from the sons of the evil one at the end of the age.
4. Everyone will be dealt with according to whom they belong.
5. "He who has ears, let him hear" meaning this is a warning and a call to change.

Comment: So whom are we to understand to be the prime mover in the matter of the bad seeds? The Good Sower? The predestined seed? The enemy sower? The plant? The soil?

Comment: @Ruminator This question should be asked of a passage that addresses that issue. This passage addresses the issues already listed. You seem to be asking "How does one become a member of the kingdom of God?" If someone is not a member of the kingdom of God then that person is a bad seed. In other passages Jesus tells us how to become a member of the kingdom. John14:6 Jesus said to him, “I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me.

Answer (score 0):

In this parable,  householder (symbolizing God) forbids his slaves to separate the wheat from the weeds while they are still growing. This is a warning to the disciples and the church not to take it upon themselves to determine those whom God will accept or reject. It is also an argument in favor of the "catholicity" of the church, meaning that both saints and sinners can be members.

The parable teaches that only the judgment of God can justly separate the sinful ones from the pure. Until then those who lead the church should preach repentance but avoid judging, for God alone is qualified to judge the hearts of men and women.

**Conclusion**: Does the parable imply a stance on theodicy in the story of Adam and Eve? It's possible to look at it that way, but that is not its intent. It is a lesson for the church to avoid playing God.

Comment: Hi Dan. I'm of the opinion that "judging" was the very role that the 144,000 played during the judgment of natural Israel and the rebirth of the United Kingdom (Israel, not Britain):

[Mat 19:28 NASB95] [28] And Jesus said to them, "Truly I say to you, that you who have followed Me, in the regeneration when the Son of Man will sit on His glorious throne, you also shall sit upon twelve thrones, judging the twelve tribes of Israel.

[Luk 22:30 NASB95] [30] that you may eat and drink at My table in My kingdom, and you will sit on thrones judging the twelve tribes of Israel.

IE: c. 70 AD/CE

Comment: [Mat 9:6-8 NKJV] [6] "But **that you may know that the Son of Man ["a human man"] has power on earth to forgive sins"**--then He said to the paralytic, "Arise, take up your bed, and go to your house." [7] And he arose and departed to his house. **[8] Now when the multitudes saw [it], they marveled and glorified God, who had given such power to men.**  It goes back to Psalm 8, Daniel 7 & 9 and so on.

Comment: @Ruminator The parable is precisely NOT about the time you refer to in your first comment. Jesus warns the disciples  to allow the wheat and weeds to grow up together until the harvest.  Re: your second comment, Jesus has the power to forgive - and perhaps his followers do as well - but they are not to attempt to separate out those who qualify for heaven from those who do not. Like the separation of the sheep and goats (Matthew 25:31) this is to be done 'When the Son of Man comes in his glory.' The church is to hold sinners as well as saints. (not that 'anything goes' either)

Comment: "When the Son of Man comes in his glory" was c. 70 AD/CE! And he was accompanied by the 144,000 and they judged God's People:

[Deu 32:36 NKJV] [36] "For the LORD will judge His people And have compassion on His servants, When He sees that [their] power is gone, And [there is] no one [remaining], bond or free.

[Psa 135:14 NKJV] [14] For the LORD will judge His people, And He will have compassion on His servants.

[Heb 10:30 NKJV] [30] For we know Him who said, "Vengeance is Mine, I will repay," says the Lord. And again, "The LORD will judge His people."

See also John 12:31.